# Passing the hyper-linked element to the hyper-linked page and receiving the element at the hyper-linked page

Tags: php, javascript

[24](http://localhost/mypage.php)

what should i do  when i just click on hyper-linked element  it just pass the elemet to the hyper-linked page as in above example 24 should pass to  http://localhost/mypage.php and how can i receive this 24 in mypage.php

Answer (score 3):

If you make a link like this:

```
<a href="mypage.php?number=24">24</a>
```

then on the receiving page you can do this:

```
$number=$_GET["number"];
```

Comment: i don't want that data should display in url please tell me  the way i can  send the data without sending through url

Comment: The short answer is you can't/shouldn't. The long answer is you could do reasonably creative things with session cookies and all sorts of other things (like abusing the POST method, changing the link at mousedown time or doing an immediate redirect). If you really need this then I'd suggest asking a new question with a title along the lines of "Passing data through a hyperlink WITHOUT include the data in the URL" and an explanation to go with it. You'll get much more help that way from other SO users. Be sure to specify if you want to hide the data from the link or the resultant page.